# spring (data, mvc, security) dependencies : IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

I have a problem with spring dependencies that I can not solve.
I use the latest versions of spring (web mvc ...), spring security and spring data.

When i compile my project with maven, I have a successful build, but when I start tomcat, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

Here are my maven dependencies:

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    <spring.asm.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.asm.version>

    <hibernate-validator.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.2.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>
    <validation.version>1.0.0.GA</validation.version>

    <postgresql.version>9.0-801.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
    <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>

    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <easymock.version>3.1</easymock.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.6</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>


    <jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>

    <joda.time.version>2.2</joda.time.version>
    <guava.version>14.0.1</guava.version>

    <antlr.version>2.7.7</antlr.version>
    <cglib.nodep.version>3.0</cglib.nodep.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JACKSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- TESTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- UTILS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DATES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Have you an idea about how i can resolvethis problem please ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** 
here is my mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ schoolme ---
[INFO] com.xtapps.schoolme.server:schoolme:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.xtapps.schoolme.server:business-layer:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.xtapps.schoolme.common:datasource-config:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.xtapps.schoolme.server:data-access-layer:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
```

here is my parent pom project :

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring.data.jpa.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

here is my pom project

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <hibernate.version>4.2.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>1.0.1.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version>
    <postgresql.version>9.0-801.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
    <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
    <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <schoolme.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</schoolme.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.12</jackson.version>
    <joda.time.version>2.2</joda.time.version>
    <guava.version>14.0.1</guava.version>
    <jaxb-api.version>2.1</jaxb-api.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA - HIBERNATE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SERVLET API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JACKSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TESTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- UTILS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DATES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
-->
</dependencies>
```

I always have the same error. 
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Why would you want to use different versions of spring JARS.. ?

Comment: The lest versions of spring is 3.2.3.RELEASE, spring security is 3.1.4.RELEASE and spring data 1.3.4.RELEASE. I don't think that i use different versions of spring jars...

Comment: Can you post your maven hierarchy.. ? Can you check the hierarchy for any incompatible JARS.. ?

Comment: i've edited my post to add maven dependencies tree and the new pom. Thanks

Comment: U did remove the conflicts right..? Can you run the code and check if you get the same error.. ?

Comment: I always have the same error...

Comment: Compiled POM myself. Didn't find any conflicts. Try tinkering with maven dependencies. You'll find the right configuration.

Comment: i don't have conflicts in maven install or build. I get it when i launch tomcat. – slim 28 mins ago

Comment: The root cause of this issue is JAR dependent. There is surely some conflicting JAR in your classpath. You will have to resolve some dependencies or smthg like that. Can't help you more. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing all the, duplicate, exclusions use a `<dependencyManagement>` block [Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management). That forces the use of specific versions of a library.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>     
</dependencyManagement>
```

In your dependency tree you have an old version of spring-orm, include that in your dependency list. (Although adding a `<dependencyManagement />` block will also fix that as it version is automatically upgraded to 3.2.3).

Finally figure out which dependency is pulling in spring-asm.jar and exclude that. Spring 3.2 and up have their own ASM version included and don't need a separate jar anymore, it is now included in the spring-core.jar.More information on changed/updates in spring 3.2 check [the reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html).

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- SPRING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SECURITY -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JACKSON -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- TESTS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- UTILS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DATES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Regarding your other dependencies the jpa-api and validator-api are automatically included by including hibernate. Also you need hibernate-validator 4.3.1.Final (there is no 4.2.3.Final).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it doesn't resolve my problem. I have a parent pom in my project. I put spring dependencies in dependencymanagement like you said, and dependencies without versions in project pom. I always have the same error. I don't have it when i build with maven (maven build, install etc). This problem appear when i start tomcat (on intellij).

Comment: I'm using also javax.servlet-api, javax.inject and mockito-all (for rest tests)

Comment: When i searched ClassVisitor type on intellij, i found three interfaces. The first one is in spring core, the second in mockito (I deleted it but I had the same error) and the last one in com.sun.xml.internal.ws.org.objectweb.asm (jdk 1.7, rt.jar).

Comment: The problem is you are pulling in a spring-asm dependency (or an older spring jar) from somewhere. Do a `mvn dependency:tree` and see which spring versions are comming in. Another option is to use the [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) with the [dependency converge rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) that will probably trigger a failed build.

Comment: when i execute "mvn dep:tree", there is only 3.2.3.RELEASE version of spring jars, and i don't have asm anymore. i'll do tonight that you suggested me after (converge, enforcer). thank you

Comment: Try to search for that jar/dependency in other locations (you don't have added any jars to your tomcat servers lib directory or something like that?). Could you update your question with the current pom and output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: i've edited my post. The new parent project pom, project pom and the dependencies tree are in the edit section. I always have the same problem... (i've upgraded spring to 3.2.4.RELEASE)

Comment: As I mentioned a couple of times before you are pulling in **spring-asm.jar**... Exclude it or remove it but you MUST remove that else you will always run into this problem...

Comment: i don't have it in my pom files. i don't see it in dependencies tree... and I added the exclusions in spring-security and spring-data. I don't understand...

Comment: i think there is a problem with intellij cache... even if I make a 'invalidate caches', I think the classpath does not update. I imported the project in eclipse, and i don't have this error... i have another one :)

Comment: sorry... After multiple tests, builds, cache clearing ... I fixed the problem. The IntelliJ cache was not up to date.... it has the old code and librairies. thanks a lot.